# InvalidCastException when setting up handler for COM event

Tags: c#, events, com, iconnectionpoint

I have an unmanaged C++ COM server that is setup to fire events, and i am trying to handle these events from my C# app.

However, I get an InvalidCastException when setting up the handler

```
myCOMObj.MyCOMEvent += new MyCOMSource_MyCOMEventHandler(handler);
```

The stack trace shows:

> Specified cast is not valid. at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint.Advise(Object pUnkSink, Int32& dwCookie) at
>   MyCOMSource_EventProvider.add_MyCOMEvent(MyCOMSource_MyCOMEventHandler) at
>   MyCOMSource_Event.add_MyCOMEvent(MyCOMSource_MyCOMEventHandler)

I have tried setting up my own IConnectionPoint like this

```
IConnectionPointContainer connectionPointContainer = (IConnectionPointContainer)myCOMObj;
Guid sourceGuid = typeof(MyCOMSource).GUID;
IConnectionPoint connectionPoint;
connectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref sourceGuid, out connectionPoint);
int cookie;
connectionPoint.Advise(myEventNotifier, out cookie);
```

where `myEventNotifier` is an object of class defined like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class EventNotifier : MyCOMSource
...
```

But i get the same InvalidCastException at `connectionPoint.Advise` with the stack trace

> Specified cast is not valid. at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IConnectionPoint.Advise(Object pUnkSink, Int32& pdwCookie)

I'm assuming this is an issue on the client side because of the consistent behavior when i try to do my own ConnnectionPoint stuff and when i let the framework do it for me. But in case it's something on the server side:

On the COM server side i have declared it like this

```
coclass MyCOMCoClass
{
    [default] dispinterface MyCOMInterface;
    [default, source] dispinterface MyCOMSource;
};
```

I have the `CONNECTION_MAP` and `CONNECTION_PART`macros in place in my class as well.

What could be going on, how can i debug this?

Answer (score 2):

MyEventHandler's GUID has to equal sourceGuid AND the current assembly HAS to be COMVisible.